# How to add new field in the Default API response

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I need add a new field in the response of cart totals API **example.com /rest/V1/carts/mine/totals/**. In order to do that, I used new interface which extends the actual interface **Magento\Quote\Api\Data\TotalsInterface** and created corresponding model which extends `\Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\Totals`.
Company\MobileApi\Api\Quote\TotalsInterface

```
    <?php
namespace Company\MobileApi\Api\Quote;

    interface TotalsInterface extends \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\TotalsInterface
    {
        /**
         * free shipping amount.
         */
        const KEY_FREE_SHIPPING_AMOUNT = 'free_shipping_amount';
        /**
         * Get free shipping amount
         *
         * @return float|null
         */
        public function getFreeShippingAmount();

        /**
         * Set ree shipping amount in quote
         *
         * @param float $freeShippingAmount
         * @return $this
         */
        public function setFreeShippingAmount($freeShippingAmount);
    }
```

**Company\MobileApis\Api\Quote\Totals**

```
<?php
```

namespace Faya\MobileApis\Api\Quote;
    use Faya\MobileApi\Api\Quote\TotalsInterface;

```
class Totals extends \Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\Totals implements TotalsInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        $this->config = $scopeConfig;
    }
    /**
     * Get free shipping amount
     *
     * @return float|null
     */
    public function getFreeShippingAmount() {
        return $this->getData(500);
        //return $this->config->getValue('carriers/ups/free_shipping_subtotal');
    }

    /**
     * Set grand total in quote currency
     *
     * @param float $freeShippingAmount
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setFreeShippingAmount($freeShippingAmount) {
        return $this->setData(self::KEY_FREE_SHIPPING_AMOUNT, 500);
    }
}
```

**Then in the API main class**

```
public function __construct(
        \Company\MobileApi\Api\Quote\TotalsInterface $totalsFactory
    ) {
        $this->totalsFactory = $totalsFactory;
    }
public function get($cartId)
    {
        $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
        $quoteTotals = $this->totalsFactory->create();
        $this->dataObjectHelper->populateWithArray(
            $quoteTotals,
            $addressTotalsData,
            '\Company\MobileApi\Api\Quote\TotalsInterface'
        );
        $items = [];
        foreach ($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $index => $item) {
            $items[$index] = $this->itemConverter->modelToDataObject($item);
        }
        $calculatedTotals = $this->totalsConverter->process($addressTotals);
        $quoteTotals->setTotalSegments($calculatedTotals);

        $amount = $quoteTotals->getGrandTotal() - $quoteTotals->getTaxAmount();
        $amount = $amount > 0 ? $amount : 0;
        $quoteTotals->setCouponCode($this->couponService->get($cartId));
        $quoteTotals->setGrandTotal($amount);
        $quoteTotals->setItems($items);
        $quoteTotals->setFreeShippingAmount(200.00);
        //return $quoteTotals->setFreeShippingAmount(200.00);//return []
        return $quoteTotals;
    }
```

In the response of API, I'm not able to get the new variable.

I think, I'm missing something to get a variable in response. Can anyone help on this?